# Why can I claim that one of these ideals must be 1 in a proof regarding primality of ideals for cyclotomic fields?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

In Washington's Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields, we are given the following lemma (1.4):

The ideal $(1 - \zeta)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathscr{O}$ and $(1 - \zeta)^{p-1}$= (p).
Therefore p is totally ramified in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta).$

The proof is straightforward for the most part, but I'm a little confused on his alternative proof of the primality.

Let's assume $(1-\zeta) = A \cdot B.$   Then $(p) = N(1-\zeta) = NA \cdot NB.$ 
This makes sense, and I'm sure I'm missing a simple fact about prime ideals, but why then can we say either NA or NB is 1?

Comment: $p=NA\cdot NB$ and of course, $p$ is a prime number.

Comment: I think there are 3 steps : first, find the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$, then prove that $N(1-\zeta^j)=N_{K/Q}(1-\zeta^j) = p$ thus $(p) = \prod_{j=1}^{p-1}(1-\zeta^j)$ is the factorization of $(p)$ in maximal ideals, finally say that for maximal ideals $m_1\subset m_2\implies m_1=m_2$ thus $(1-\zeta^j)=(1-\zeta)$